# In Star Trek, what was the name of Benjamin Sisko's favorite ship?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

I'm trying to register on Sf Debris' forum, but the registration question is “What is Benjamin Sisko's favorite ship called?”

I've used The Defiant or USS Defiant but it tells me it's incorrect. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried just "Defiant"?

Comment: Why do you have to answer a question to register on a forum, that just seems silly.

Comment: Probably as a filter to weed out bots. Also to prove sf geekiness I guess.

Comment: Try "Friendship" hur hur :)

Comment: It'll be some variation of Defiant. Maybe "The USS Defiant"?

Comment: We first meet him as he is abandoning the USS Saratoga - it would crazy to call that his favorite ship but it's another option

Comment: His first ship (at least according to Wikipedia) was the USS Livingston and then he served on the USS Okinawa - give those a try?

Comment: Maybe it's Locustus' Borg Cube?   :<

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the underlying problem was (functionally) a typo.

Comment: There was that time he built a ship powered by solar sails. Memory Alpha says he named it "Baraka."

Comment: I tried just Defiant as you suggested and worked. Thanks

Comment: This has gone into the Close review queue at least twice.  My argument for leaving it open is that while the reason for the question is off-topic (registering on a forum), the actual question is on-topic.  If you find the current formulation problematic, perhaps an edit would be in order.

Answer (score 11):

I've just joined [Sfdebris's forum](http://sfdebris.net/forum/index.php). The answer is

> Defiant <sub><sup>(with or without a Capital D)</sup></sub>.

Answer (score 3):

They might be referring to [the lightship](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sisko's_lightship) that Sisko built, and sailed to Cardassia with his son.

It wasn’t named in the episode, but apparently in a deleted scene it was christened “Baraka”.

Comment: Not a lot of people would be able to register if doing so depended on that relatively obscure piece of information.

Comment: @HamSandwich All wheat! No chaff!